# Composer (Airflow) DAG RunID conflict in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We have one cloud function, which is cloud storage based. This cloud function will trigger once the file loaded into the bucket.
When file loaded, the function will call/trigger the airflow DAG. This DAG will process the file.

The issue is, when multiple files placed same time with in a second, the function call is failing with the below error,

> b'{"error":"Run id manual__2020-07-31T17:48:15+00:00 already exists for dag id pl_imaoc_trigger_dag"}\n'
>
> To resolve this issue we passing the run_id as 'run_id': 'IMAOC_31072020201842766625', date with milliseconds.

Code:

```
dag_name = environ_vars['imaoc_meta_dag']
    webserver_url = (
        webserver_id
        + '/api/experimental/dags/'
        + dag_name
        + '/dag_runs'
    )

    print('webserver_url: {}'.format(webserver_url))
    data['run_id'] = _datetime.datetime.now().strftime(**"IMAOC_%d%m%Y%H%M%S%f"**)
    resp = map_iap_request(webserver_url,client_id,method = 'POST',json = data)
    print('response text:{}'.format(resp))
```

But still it's not resolved, and AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID is coming as "manual__2020-07-31T20:18:43+00:00" format....

No idea what to do for remove this conflict and trigger the DAG, if the file coming on the same second.

Comment: Is there any option to set the AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID variable before the DAG run..?

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code it working

```
client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
# This should be part of your webserver's URL:
# {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com
webserver_id = os.getenv("TENANT_PROJECT")
# The name of the DAG you wish to trigger
dag_name = os.getenv("DAG_NAME")
webserver_url = (
    'https://'
    + webserver_id
    + '.appspot.com/api/experimental/dags/'
    + dag_name
    + '/dag_runs'
)
# Make a POST request to IAP which then Triggers the DAG
run_id = datetime.utcnow().strftime('alpaca_%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

conf = {"conf": data}
print(f"JSON body = {conf}")

make_iap_request(
    webserver_url, client_id, method='POST', json={"conf": data, "run_id": run_id, "replace_microseconds": False})
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. The cloud function isn't triggering at all.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer worked for me by adding `"replace_microseconds": False` in the conf file as shown below

```
run_id = 'trig__'+datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
conf['replace_microseconds'] = False
response = requests.post(URL, headers=Header, json={"conf": conf, "run_id": run_id})
```